# An error has occurred during the upload process in wordpress 5.3.2

Tags: images, uploads, errors

I need your help , i try upload to wordpress an image but there is error ‘An error has occurred during the upload process in wordpress’ , please help me find solution. ASAP

Note : this website http://eliteclub.co.id/

Answer (score 0):

Which Browser are you using? I had some problems with 5.3.2 and Uploading in Safari Browser. Using Chrome or Firefox fixed the problem for me.